# Where can I ask a question about team email account management

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for resources or information on approaches for managing a shared (tech support) email account. Where is the best place to post please? I would have expected server fault, but it seems more tech than process?

(Just to add - I really have already Googled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's SF, be sure.

Both tech and process fit into description of site from [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions) "Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity". IT is not only hardware, even "IT is mostly non-hardware"